# Android UsageStats INTERVAL_DAILY not working

Tags: java, android, kotlin, usage-statistics, usagestatsmanager

I'm trying to get the totalTimeInForeground from the UsageStats in the current day, my code is:

```
val calendar = Calendar.getInstance()
       calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY,0)
       calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE,0)
       calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND,0)

       val usageStatsManager = mContext.getSystemService(Context.USAGE_STATS_SERVICE) as UsageStatsManager
   usageStatsManager.queryUsageStats(UsageStatsManager.INTERVAL_DAILY, calendar.timeInMillis, System.currentTimeMillis())
```

Problem is that it's retrieving data from the day before, even the [getFirstTimeStamp](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/usage/UsageStats#getFirstTimeStamp()) is from the day before.

I know this has been asked before and it's a common problem, but in my research I didn't find any concrete solution.

Thanks in advice.